# Run Node.js script via command line or ES6 import

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, es6-modules

How do I write a Node script that can be run from either the command line or via an ES6 import statement?

I am using the `--experimental-modules` flag and `.mjs` extension to run scripts as ES6 modules.

## Example

Say I have the following script in `sayHello.mjs`:

```js
export default function sayHello() {
  console.log(`Hello!`);
}
```

I would like to be able to use this script in the following two ways:

1. Via the command line:

   ```
   node --experimental-modules sayHello.mjs
   ```
2. Via an ES6 import statement in another script:

   ```js
   import sayHello from './sayHello.mjs';

   sayHello();
   ```

## Details

I am looking for a solution similar to using `module.main` for CommonJS modules (this does not work for ES6 imports):

```js
if (require.main === module) {
    console.log('run from command line');
} else {
    console.log('required as a module');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
function sayHello() { console.log("Hello"); }
if (process.env.CL == 1){
    sayHello();
} else {
    export default sayHello;
}
```

From commandline, use:

```
CL=1 node --experimental-modules sayHello.mjs
```

Pretty simple, but it should work

Another option is to check `process.argv[1]` since it should always be [the filename that was specified from the commandline](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_argv):

```
if (process.argv[1].indexOf("sayHello.mjs") > -1){
    sayHello();
} else {
    export default sayHello;
}
```